# Parsing error: Unexpected token When trying to use JQuery with React JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

Right now i am learning react.js and i am trying to add a side nav bar to my home page but when i try to write the code in jquery for that sidebar then i got eslint error.
Below is the code of side nave bar.

I tried installing jquery in node-modules with the command `npm install jquery --save` but still i am getting same issue.

I tried to find the solution on google for about 3 hour but still didn't get the right solution.

Someone please fix this issue for me.

```
import $ from jQuery;

let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
let options_menus = document.querySelector(".lwm");
let closeBtn = document.querySelector("#btn");
let searchBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-search");


let arrow = document.querySelectorAll(".lwm");

  for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
    arrow[i].addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
  
   let arrowParent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;//selecting main parent of arrow
  
   arrowParent.classList.toggle("showMenu");
    });
  }


closeBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
  
  sidebar.classList.toggle("open");
  debugger

  if(options_menus.classList.contains("showMenu"))
  {
    //options_menus.classList.toggle("showMenu");
    $(".nav-list").find("li").removeClass("showMenu");
  }
  menuBtnChange();//calling the function(optional)
});

searchBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{ // Sidebar open when you click on the search iocn
  sidebar.classList.toggle("open");
  menuBtnChange(); //calling the function(optional)
});

// following are the code to change sidebar button(optional)
function menuBtnChange() {
 if(sidebar.classList.contains("open")){
   closeBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu", "bx-menu-alt-right");//replacing the iocns class
 }else {
   closeBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu-alt-right","bx-menu");//replacing the iocns class
 }
}
```

This is my App.js

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import "./nav.css";
import "./nav.js";


let Menu_Icon = "./icons/menu.svg";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div uk-sticky="sel-target: .uk-navbar-container; cls-active: uk-navbar-sticky">



<div class="sidebar open">
    <div class="logo-details">
        <i class='icon'><img class="sms_logo" src="./images/sms_logo_v0.1.svg" alt=""/></i>

        <div class="logo_name">PP_BMK</div>
        <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-list">
        
        <li>
            <a href="./index.html">
                <i class='icon'>
                    
                </i>
                <span class="links_name">Dashboard</span>
            </a>
            <span class="tooltip">Dashboard</span>
        </li>
        <li class="lwm">
            <div class="iocn-link">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class='icon'>
                        
                    </i>
                    <span class="links_name">Keasy Warner</span>
                    <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down links_name arrow'></i>
                </a>
                <span class="tooltip">Certificates</span>

            </div>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="./pages/charcter_certificate.html">Charcter Certificate</a></li>
                <li><a href="./pages/provisional_certificate.html">Provisnal Certificate</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Diplooma/Degree</a></li>
                <li><a href="./pages/migration_certificat.html">Migration Certificate</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="lwm">
            <div class="iocn-link">
                <a href="#">
                    <i class='bx bx-book'></i>
                    <span class="links_name">Exams</span>
                    <i class='bx bxs-chevron-down links_name arrow'></i>
                </a>
                <span class="tooltip">Exam</span>

            </div>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="./pages/exam_attendance_sheet.html">Exam Attendance Sheet</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Result Declration</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Paper Print</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Paper Edit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>


    </ul>
</div>




</div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />

    <!-- UIkit CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.16.13/dist/css/uikit.min.css" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
 
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />

    

    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>

  


    


    <!-- UIkit JS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.16.13/dist/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.16.13/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

This is the error i am getting.

```
ERROR in ./src/nav.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\src\nav.js: Unexpected token (1:14)

> 1 | import $ from jQuery;
    |               ^
  2 |
  3 | let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  4 | let options_menus = document.querySelector(".lwm");
    at instantiate (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:653:32)
    at constructor (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:947:12)
    at FlowParserMixin.raise (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3271:19)
    at FlowParserMixin.unexpected (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:3301:16)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseImportSource (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14075:32)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseImport (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14059:24)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatementContent (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12664:27)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatementLike (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12557:17)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseStatementLike (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5149:24)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseModuleItem (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12534:17)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseBlockOrModuleBlockBody (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13129:36)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseBlockBody (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:13122:10)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseProgram (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12445:10)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseTopLevel (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12435:25)
    at FlowParserMixin.parseTopLevel (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:5969:28)
    at FlowParserMixin.parse (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14258:10)
    at parse (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:14299:38)
    at parser (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\parser\index.js:41:34)
    at parser.next (<anonymous>)
    at normalizeFile (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\normalize-file.js:64:38)
    at normalizeFile.next (<anonymous>)
    at run (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\index.js:21:50)
    at run.next (<anonymous>)
    at transform (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transform.js:22:41)
    at transform.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\gensync\index.js:261:32)
    at D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\gensync\index.js:273:13
    at async.call.result.err.err (D:\My Work\projects\vs\PP_BMK\p_bmk\node_modules\gensync\index.js:223:11)
ERROR
[eslint] 
src\nav.js
  Line 1:14:  Parsing error: Unexpected token (1:14)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import jquery like this

```
import $ from "jquery" ;
```

Another thing

In your nav.js, you declare some variables and start using them without checking if they are already available in the DOM.

When you import the nav.js file into your App.js file, this js code will start running before the return function, so before your DOM is ready.

What I suggest doing is putting all the jquery code in a useEffect hook in your App.js or, if you want to separate these files, use the jquery ready function like this.

```
import $ from "jquery";

$(function() {
  let sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");
  let options_menus = document.querySelector(".lwm");
  let closeBtn = document.querySelector("#btn");
  let searchBtn = document.querySelector(".bx-search");

  let arrow = document.querySelectorAll(".lwm");

  for (var i = 0; i < arrow.length; i++) {
    arrow[i].addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      let arrowParent = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement; //selecting main parent of arrow

      arrowParent.classList.toggle("showMenu");
    });
  }

  closeBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    sidebar.classList.toggle("open");
    debugger;

    if (options_menus.classList.contains("showMenu")) {
      //options_menus.classList.toggle("showMenu");
      $(".nav-list").find("li").removeClass("showMenu");
    }
    menuBtnChange(); //calling the function(optional)
  });

  searchBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Sidebar open when you click on the search iocn
    sidebar.classList.toggle("open");
    menuBtnChange(); //calling the function(optional)
  });

  // following are the code to change sidebar button(optional)
  function menuBtnChange() {
    if (sidebar.classList.contains("open")) {
      closeBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu", "bx-menu-alt-right"); //replacing the iocns class
    } else {
      closeBtn.classList.replace("bx-menu-alt-right", "bx-menu"); //replacing the iocns class
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The parsing error is gone but getting a new errors.



`Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at ./src/nav.js (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:526:10)`

Comment: ok I have adjusted my answer to fix that